# How are Stacks and Queues "special cases" of a list?

Tags: list, stack, queue

For my test tomorrow, I will need to be able to:

> explain how stack and queue are special cases of a list.

Does anyone know a good place where I can read about this? A Google searches can't help me with this one, it's one of those "We discussed this in class, don't ask me again" type of questions.

Comment: "List" can mean a lot of things. What kind(s) of list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List supports insertion and deletion at any place.
Queue supports insertion at tail and deletion at front.
Stack supports insertion and deletion from top.

It's easy to see that queues and stacks support only a subset of list operations. **In this sense** they are special cases of a list.

Comment: (+1) I think this is as good an answer as any. I also think that the question is extremely poorly worded.

Comment: Well, it doesn't claim that stack or queue **is a** list... I suppose it's not so bad for academic purposes

Comment: +1, plus a nit: a list is just a sequence of elements; it need not support insertion or deletion at all. That is, an unmodifiable list is still a useful data structure. On the other hand, an unmodifiable queue or stack is pretty useless.

Comment: @TedHopp It's an "it depends" nit. I'd chalk it up to "list" being a vaguely defined term. icepack might have had the term in mind as what it means in the Java/.NET/Python standard libraries, where an immutable list is a special case of a "normal" list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a book by Robert Lafore called [Data Structures and Algorithms in java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672324539).

Read first six chapters (I might be wrong, maybe more) and you should be pretty good with all data structures(most commonly used).

Answer (score 1):

A stack is a list that only allows you to add (push) and remove (pop) from the 'top'.

[image]

A queue is a list that only allows adding to the 'back' (enqueue) and removing from the from 'front' (dequeue).

[image]

See:

[Wikipedia: List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type))

[Wikipedia: Stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type))

[Wikipedia: Queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type))